# Row number over partitions with is only unique if ConsecutiveNumber is non unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, window-functions

I need to have a row number which is unique for Items with a unique ConsecutiveNumber, however, if the ConsecutiveNumber occurs more than ones the row number should be the same. But I'm struggling to obtain the desired result. Any help would be much appreciated.

The desired result can be seen in the table below **targetOutput**.

```
SELECT InvoiceNr,ConsecutiveNumber,ItemNr
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNr, InvoiceNr
                           ORDER BY  ItemNr, InvoiceNr) as currentOutput
FROM someTable
```

```
InvoiceNr   ConsecutiveNumber   ItemNr          currentOutput   targetOutput    
20001222    118                 h46f4-22-05     1               1
20001222    343                 h46f4-22-05     2               2
20001222    1243                h46f4-22-05     3               3
20001222    1991                h46f4-22-05     4               4
20001222    461                 n8-91           1               1
20001222    1495                n8-91           2               2
20001222    1495                n8-91           3               2
20001222    1495                n8-91           4               2
20001222    1844                pibb53-3-x      1               1
20001222    1844                pibb53-3-x      2               1
20001222    1844                pibb53-3-x      3               1
```

Comment: Use dense_rank() rather than row_number()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a number that honors ties and that increasing sequentially without gaps.

You are describing `dense_rank()`. I think that you want:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY ItemNr, InvoiceNr 
    ORDER BY ConsecutiveNumber
) as currentOutput
```

Note that it usually makes little or no sense to have the same columns in the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses. The former defines the groups of rows, while the latter defines the ordering of rows within groups. Using `ROW_NUMBER()` as you did actually ended up with undefined rows indexes within the groups (numbers could have been assigned in any order within groups).

Answer (score 1):

GMB Beat me to it. Note, the diff between Rank and Dense_rank. Either could work depending on what you are looking for. I added an additional row.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
  InvoiceNr         BIGINT,
  ConsecutiveNumber INT,
  ItemNr            VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT @table VALUES
(20001222,118 ,'h46f4-22-05'),
(20001222,343 ,'h46f4-22-05'),
(20001222,1243,'h46f4-22-05'),
(20001222,1991,'h46f4-22-05'),
(20001222,461 ,'n8-91'),
(20001222,1495,'n8-91'),
(20001222,1495,'n8-91'),
(20001222,1495,'n8-91'),
(20001222,1844,'pibb53-3-x'),
(20001222,1844,'pibb53-3-x'),
(20001222,1844,'pibb53-3-x'),
(20001222,1845,'pibb53-3-x'); -- New record

SELECT 
  t.*,
  [RANK]       = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNr, InvoiceNr
                                    ORDER BY  ConsecutiveNumber),
  [DENSE_RANK] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNr, InvoiceNr
                                    ORDER BY  ConsecutiveNumber)
FROM @table AS t;
```

**Results:**

```
InvoiceNr    ConsecutiveNumber ItemNr          RANK   DENSE_RANK
------------ ----------------- --------------- ------ -------------
20001222     118               h46f4-22-05     1      1
20001222     343               h46f4-22-05     2      2
20001222     1243              h46f4-22-05     3      3
20001222     1991              h46f4-22-05     4      4
20001222     461               n8-91           1      1
20001222     1495              n8-91           2      2
20001222     1495              n8-91           2      2
20001222     1495              n8-91           2      2
20001222     1844              pibb53-3-x      1      1
20001222     1844              pibb53-3-x      1      1
20001222     1844              pibb53-3-x      1      1
20001222     1845              pibb53-3-x      4      2
```

Small detail but Note the difference.